# Save filtered tree view to load as it is at another time

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10, odoo-view

So, The case is.
I filtered the records in list view by applying some filters.
So, I need any mechanism to save this listview data to load after some time by clicking on any button or something.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What about saving the filter as a favorite?

Comment: Yes, that is fine. but it may happen that on that saved filter I will get new records included but i don't want any new records.

Comment: paste your code and efforts which you were tried from your side

Comment: I am thinking that somehow I can store the filtered records in another new model by clicking on the save filter button and when clicking on load filter button it will get the records from that model.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to freeze the records as they are at the moment of the request, you'll have to save them in another model. Something like a report with the report lines containing the needed information. Otherwise, deleted records will vanish, modified records will, well - get modified.

If you'd like to get no more results, but still display the changes/deletions of the existing ones, you can either filter them by some relevant date interval for example, or again use the above mentioned approach, but keep relation fields to the actual records containing the up-to-date data.

Comment: Thank you.
I just find the solution.
I will post my answer soon.